# Attach Data To A Returned Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to reuse the same $.ajax but pass it different "settings" but not sure if I can do that or not.

```
   return $.ajax({
        method: method,
        url: url,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            // show loading
        }
    }).done(function (err) {
        // hide loading
    }).fail(function (err) {
         //hide loading
    });
```

After I return this how could I add the 'Data' setting to it so I can pass some parameters? Or do I have to write is some other way?

Answer (score 0):

i guess you are looking for a function wrap

```
function sendAjax(method,url, data, beforeSend){
  $.ajax({
        method: method,
        url: url,
        data:data,
        beforeSend: beforeSend
    }).done(function (err) {
         //hide loading
    }).fail(function (err) {
         //hide loading
    });
}
```

I just added beforeSend so you see you can also pass whole functions

```
sendAjax('POST','/api', {foo:'bar'},function(xhr){ ...})
```

Comment: Yeah that was the way I was going down, I was hoping there was something like how you can attach .done() functions at any time but just for the settings.

Comment: you could also pass the done function as parameter, also you could return the $ajax, as its a promise obj you should be able to add .done like:  `test = sendAjax(x,y,t,z); test.done(function(){...})`